# Android voice recognition dont speak

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm making an app where I ask a question and the answering machine answers me depending on the question, but the problem is that the cell phone listens but it does not respond, that is, it does not talk.

She is speak in open app with welcome, but after no talk

My code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextToSpeech myTTS;
private SpeechRecognizer mySpeechReconizer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button mic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mic);
    mic.setOnClickListener((view) ->
    {

            Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            mySpeechReconizer.startListening(i);


    });

    initializeTextToSpeech();
    initializeSpeechReconizer();
}

private void initializeSpeechReconizer() {
    if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)) {
        mySpeechReconizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mySpeechReconizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                List<String> res = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                processResult(res.get(0));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

            }
        });
    }
}

private void processResult(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();

    //Qual é o teu nome?

    if (s.indexOf("What") != -1){
        if (s.indexOf("your name") != -1){
            speak("two");
        }
        if (s.indexOf("time") != -1){
            Date now = new Date();
            String time = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,now.getTime(),
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
            speak(time);
        }
    }

     else if (s.indexOf("open") != -1){
        if (s.indexOf("browser") != -1){
        }
            speak("Sou a Lian, fui fundada pelo Leandro e moro em Baião.");
    }
}

private void initializeTextToSpeech() {
    myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (myTTS.getEngines().size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                Locale l1 = new Locale("pt","PT");
                myTTS.setLanguage(l1);
                speak("Olá Leandro, estou pronta,podes falar!");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void speak(String s) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=21){
        myTTS.speak(s,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
        } else{
        myTTS.speak(s,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myTTS.shutdown();
}
```

}

Comment: Does the `SpeechRecognizer` perhaps open a dialog which triggers your Activity's `onPause()` where you call `myTTS.shutdown()` and shut down the TTS engine?

Comment: i dont understand, plese you can be more clear?

Comment: I was wondering if there's a popup dialog when SpeechRecognizer is listening, but I guess it doesn't happen with your way of using it. That could have been a potential explanation as it could have triggered the onPause() method and killed the TTS engine.

Comment: maybe ,i don´t know